# Search tool bar hide effect

Tags: css, search, toolbar

I'm working on my search toolbar for my website. Everything is running ok, except for the hide effect of the toolbar that has a weird behaviour. The transition works fine to display the writting bar, when I clock again in the search icon its suppose to hide the full bar, but instead hides only about half. If I click outside the search toolbar the bar hides correctly. Here is my code: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nfds89/bL8gLo4b/). And the relevant code:

```
#input {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 30px;
width: 200px;
height: 30px;
z-index: 5;
overflow: hidden;}

#input input {
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: -200px;
width: 200px;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0 10px;
border: none;
background-color: #ededed;
color: #000;
font-size: 12px;
-webkit-backface-visibility: none;
-moz-backface-visibility: none;
-ms-backface-visibility: none;
backface-visibility: none;
-webkit-border-radius: 0;
-moz-border-radius: 0;
border-radius: 0;
-webkit-transition: right 0;
-moz-transition: right 0;
-ms-transition: right 0;
-o-transition: right 0;
transition: right 0;}

#input input:focus {
outline: none;}

#input.focus {
z-index: 20;}

#input.focus input {
right: 0;
-webkit-transition: right 0.3s;
-moz-transition: right 0.3s;
-ms-transition: right 0.3s;
-o-transition: right 0.3s;
transition: right 0.3s;}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please create a fiddle so we can see the problem in action

Comment: Just added the fiddle!

Comment: And please include the relevant code in the question itself as well. A fiddle is a plus, but code should always be included in the question as well.

Comment: Already included the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems the reason input box not hidding completely due to padding given for input element

```
.input input {  padding: 0 10px;
```

The actual width is calculated by browser for input box is

> `width:200px` + `padding-left:10px` + `padding-right:10px` = Actual width goes to  `220px`;

**Solution for this is by adding**

```
.input input { box-sizing:border-box;
```

property to input element class

Sample code can be seen here

```
.input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 30px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    z-index: 5;
    overflow: hidden;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
  background-color:#fff;
}

.input input {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -200px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    border: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;

    -webkit-backface-visibility: none;
    -moz-backface-visibility: none;
     -ms-backface-visibility: none;
         backface-visibility: none;

    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
     border-radius: 0;

    -webkit-transition: right -200px;
    -moz-transition: right -200px;
    -ms-transition: right -200px;
    -o-transition: right -200px;
    transition: right -200px;
}

.input input:focus  { outline: none;    }
.input.focus        { z-index: 20;      }
.input:hover input{ 
    right:0px; 
    -webkit-transition: right 0px 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: right 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: right 0.3s;
    -o-transition: right 0.3s;
    transition: right 0px 0.3s;
}

.input.focus input  {
    right:0px; 
-webkit-transition: right 0px 0.3s;
-moz-transition: right 0.3s;
-ms-transition: right 0.3s;
-o-transition: right 0.3s;
transition: right 0px 0.3s; 
}
body { font:13px 'arial'; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ShirishDhotre/9gqa2bum/

I added hover effect for demo you can remove class

```
.input:hover input{
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried to add the line box-sizing:border-box; to my css code,but still doesnt work. I also noticed that sometimes the bar hides completely, I just dont understand why some other times it doesnt and it has a random behaviour.